# What should the users of Super User be called?

Tags: discussion

This is one of those "shameless ripoff for consistency reasons" questions.  Back in September 2008, someone asked ["What should the users of Stack Overflow be called?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/what-should-the-users-of-stack-overflow-be-called).  In mid-2009, we got ["What should contributors to Server Fault be called?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/what-should-contributors-to-serverfault-be-called).  There's no equivalent Super User question yet, so... here it is.

Oddly, the SO question is `[discussion]` and `[fun]` while the SF question is the big red `[faq]`.  I'm not sure which direction to go with the tagging on this question... discussion on that in the comments is welcome.

---

I'm going to try something interesting here — a poll with strict requirements for answers. Here are the rules. Note — posts may be edited if they are out of compliance.

- Your post must contain only your desired answer
- You must not duplicate an answer
- If you do accidentally duplicate an answer, it's your responsibility to delete it. Otherwise, it will be edited to say something along the lines of "I can't follow directions."
- Observers should vote up the names they like
- Discussion should occur in the comments
- The answer with the highest number of votes will be accepted as the official answer

(*Users who have not been under a rock since 2008 will note that these are the ancestors of the current* de facto *official poll rules.*)

So... what should we, the users of Super User, be called?

Comment: Super User is also the only title containing a "user name", when the others are errors. The correct answer seems pretty obvious. Moreover that you can say "Stack Overflow users", but "Super User users" is clearly redundant.

Comment: Users are errors. @gno

Comment: @Gnoupi, I see where you're coming from, but I disagree.  I associate the site titles more closely than the words they contain.  In other words, "Super Users" makes me think of "Stack Overflows" and "Server Faults," which both fail as descriptors of SO and SF users.

Comment: @pop - so far I have seen Super users referred only this way, also, this is why I say that. However, nothing wrong with a "light" question to see what it could be instead.

Comment: I always like to refer to myself

Comment: Old question....but some of the site's users can be descripted by the site's title...for example Super Users (duh) and Programmers.. Some of them need modification for example Biologists and Chemists. Just a thought....

Answer (score 20):

Super users.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious indeed.

Comment: Okay, fine.  This answer is winner by popular vote.  You boring, boring people.

Answer (score 12):

SUdoers

Remember the [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command grants administrative, or "super", privileges.

Answer (score 7):

[Ewoks](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/).

Answer (score 4):

*...then for consistency I have to repeat my answer:*

Oh, good lord. Please, no.

The day someone starts labeling Super User user as "Supee" or a "SU-er" or a "Super Badgie" ... is the day I start *anonomous-izing* my account. Can you say "pop-culture-burnout, jumping-the-shark"?

Comment: You're a Meta Super Stacker Sysadmin Exchanger.

Comment: @The Cat: As of today, that's what it says on the top of my CV.

Comment: @Robert, well, sure; not like you're going to need to look for a new job anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Super Troopers.

Comment: Aaaaaand now it's stuck in my head.